# ERROR installing apache archiva on my sytem

Tags: apache, maven-release-plugin, archiva

[image]

Can anyone help regarding this... i'm stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto the folder apache-archiva-1.3.3 and the following:

```
.\bin\archiva.bat install
```

Comment: Are you logged in as administrator ? (Permission problem?)

Answer (score 1):

As khmarbaise says above, you probably need to log in with administrative rights.

Another alternative is to run:

```
archiva console
```

This will start it within that console - however you'll then need to keep it open and restart manually after a reboot, where a service can run in the background and start automatically.